# Passing Parameters to a custom .Net workflow activity from a process

Tags: dynamics-crm, workflow-foundation

I'm new to Dynamics CRM and need to pass some arguments to a custom C#.Net workflow activity from a process.

How would I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [Add metadata to a custom workflow activity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg327842.aspx), for example:

```
[Input("EntityReference input")]
[Output("EntityReference output")]
[ReferenceTarget("account")]
public InOutArgument<EntityReference> AccountReference { get; set; }
```

Which can then be accessed like so:

```
protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
{
   EntityReference account = AccountReference.Get(context);
}
```

Explore the related articles on the link above for more information.